# iTerm as default terminal for Anaconda

Tags: macos, terminal, anaconda, jupyter

I just installed Anaconda (with GUI) for data science projects. I'm a Mac user and when I launch Jupiter notebook from Anaconda Navigator it runs macOS default terminal. Is there a way to set Anaconda for using iTerm2 as terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the default installation of anaconda (and iterm2).

1. **Make sure, iTerm2 is an default term** - this probably wont help, but... Do that :D

- Open iTerm, navigate in menu on `iTerm2` > `Make iTerm2 default term`

---

2. When you open the jupyter for example from anaconda, default terminal launches with the script. The name of this script file should be located at the top, by default it is: */opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command*
3. **Navigate to */opt/anaconda3/bin/* folder**, or any other one where the command file from previous step is.

- from terminal: `open /opt/anaconda3/bin/` which will open finder in this destination)

4. In this folder, **locate the jupyter_mac.command file**
5. *CMD+I* on this file (or right-click and select Get Info)
6. This will open Information window for this file. Under the accordion, there is a selection of "Open with".
7. Instead of terminal, select iTerm2
8. Ideally, click on Change All... button so all the .command files will launch in iTerm

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer, this worked for me. One note - on my system my anaconda3 opt folder is in `~/anaconda3/bin` (probably because I have anaconda installed just for my user, and not all users).

Answer (score 1):

If you open iterm2 and go to the toolbar(on the top of the screen), try iTerm2-make iterm2 default term. See if this changes the behavior.

If not and you prefer using iTerm2, you can always open up an iTerm2 window and simply type

```
jupyter notebook
```

And you should have a jupyter notebook open in your browser, with the process running in the iTerm2 window.